# Capture Screenshots at Defined Time Intervals Automatically using asp.net c# web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I have one online test website, and I want to capture a screenshot at defined time intervals, automatically, using ASP.NET C# Web Forms. I need other related sample code.

I had tried one way. Now I am getting a URL, using capture the HTML response from an HTTP request. I want to store the HTML Image in a database table. I'm not getting any ideas regarding this.

Below is my C# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getimage();
}

public void getimage()
 {
   WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
    string myPageHTML = null;
    byte[] requestHTML;
    // Gets the url of the page
    string currentPageUrl = Request.Url.ToString();

    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

       // by setting currentPageUrl to mypage.aspx it will fetch the source (html) 
    // of the mypage.aspx and put it in the myPageHTML variable. 

    currentPageUrl = "http://localhost:49161/login.aspx";

    requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData(currentPageUrl);

    myPageHTML = utf8.GetString(requestHTML);

    Response.Write(myPageHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want take a screenshot of the entire page or just save the response HTML? It is not the same thing. Getting the response HTML not always gives you the final rendered HTML because of scripts that are executed on client side.